# Spring AOP aspect around is not executing

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I want to record execution time of my service method.
I think AOP  is a easy way to do, so I wrote an Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class ServiceLogAdviceAspect {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceLogAdviceAspect.class);

    @Around("execution(* com.j1.**.service.*(..))")
    public Object doBasicProfilingTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object target = joinPoint.getTarget();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOG.error(String.format("Invoke [%s$%s] Takes %d ms", target.getClass().getCanonicalName(), methodName, (end - start)));
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

and Spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
        default-autowire="byName">
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <bean id="logAdviceAspect" 
        class="com.j1.soa.common.aspect.ServiceLogAdviceAspect"></bean>
</beans>
```

But when I invoke the method
`public ServiceMessage<GoodsDetailDto> getGoodDetail(GoodsDetailDto goodsDetailDto)`

I get neither error output nor into the breakpoint.

---

**EDIT**

`getGoodDetail` is defined in class
`com.j1.soa.resource.item.service.GoodsDetailServiceImpl`

And I am calling it using Hessian RPC,

First defined spring bean of Remote Service in `application-context-rpc.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="goodsDetailService" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://api.soa.item.j1.com/hessian/goodsDetailService" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.j1.soa.resource.item.api.GoodsDetailService" />
        <property name="readTimeout" value="6000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then defined it in client

```
@Autowired
private GoodsDetailService goodsDetailService;
```

And using it

```
GoodsDetailDto goodsDetailDto = new GoodsDetailDto();
goodsDetailDto.setGoodsId(NumericUtil.parseLong(goodsId));
goodsDetailDto.setProductId(NumericUtil.parseInt(productId));
goodsDetailDto.setSiteType(SiteType.MOBILE);

ServiceMessage<GoodsDetailDto> detailResult = goodsDetailService
                .getGoodDetail(goodsDetailDto);
```

Comment: please share where getGoodDetail() method class is defined and how it's defined in the spring context

Comment: Show the code that's calling `getGoodDetail`.

Comment: First of all how are you calling this method? Second your point cut is wrong it should be something along the lines of `execution(* com.j1..service.*(..))`.

Comment: I note that you're using namespaces from mixed versions going as far back as *Spring 2.0*, which is barely recognizable as modern Spring. Start by using a consistent version, preferably 4.

Answer (score 0):

You should include `logAdviceAspect` in `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="logAdviceAspect"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```